# Large data set-ssis DT_WSTR Field allocating space in buffer ETL SSIS to Varchar Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am pushing a large dataset into SQL via SSIS. I am trying to squeeze more performance out of SSIS ETL ( no transformations)

We have some `DT_WSTR` fields that are sized as 1000 in SSIS and in SQL we have it also as 1000 as varchar. When running a max size it is around 200 in total size. I know Varchar in SQL will only take up the size it needs in the record. How is this handled when passed over through SSIS does it take and pass over as the full 1000? is there any performance benefit by putting it down to 200 in both SQL and SSIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is either remove the column, or reduce the size. It's possible that you have to truncate data in order to get a smaller size.

If you need the full data, you can change the `DefaultBufferSize` to a much higher value. This will use more memory so that larger buffers can be used.